# gulp rename multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-rename

I have a gulp script to manipulate a master html file and rename it into several name based on an array. here's the script.

```
    gulp.task('default', function () {
      var data = ['name1','name2'];
      for(var name in data){              
         gulp.src('src/master.html')
           .pipe(*dosomething...*)
           .pipe(rename(function(path) {
              path.basename = name;
              path.extname = '.html';
          }))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
      }
    });
```

But only the name2.html is generated. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code.

Comment: How do you construct path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't make functions within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Your loop creates multiple functions that you pass to `rename`. Each of those functions refers to the same variable `name`. However those functions aren't executed immediately, but only after *all* of them have been created. That means *all* your functions refer to the last value that `name` had in the loop.

You need to create multiple `name` variables by replacing your `for` loop with a looping construct that creates a new function scope for each value, e.g. [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

You are also creating multiple streams in your loop. You should return those streams after merging them with [`merge-stream`](https://npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) so gulp can [determine when your task has finished](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support).

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  var data = ['name1','name2'];
  var streams = [];
  data.forEach(function(name) {
    var stream = gulp.src('src/master.html')
      .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        path.basename = name;
        path.extname = '.html';
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    streams.push(stream);
  });
  return merge(streams);
});
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. By the way, what if data is a json object instead of array. forEach isn't available for object

Comment: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of the object's keys, which let's you use `.forEach()` again: `Object.keys(jsonObject).forEach(function(key) {`

Answer (score 0):

`for ... in` is intended for looping through the keys of an object. For an array, the keys are the index values (0 and 1), so I'm surprised `name2.html` is being generated at all - perhaps it was already there from a previous run.

Either change to an indexed for loop `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ...` or get the name from the array using `path.basename = data[name];`